# Convert HTML table in to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I am tring to convert the html table data into something like this:
**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/y2gdq/7/)**

```
[{
    name: 'Week 1',
    data: [33.95, 40.68]},
{
    name: 'Week 2',
    data: [11.99, 16.66]},
{
    name: 'Week 3',
    data: [1.96, 0.93]},
{
    name: 'Week 4',
    data: [0, 1.21]}]
```

**Method I am using:**

```
var Consolelog = $('table tbody tr').map(function() {

    var $row = $(this);
    return {
        name: $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text(),
        data: $('td:not(:nth-child(1))', this).each( function(){

            $(this).text();

        })
    };


}).get();

console.log(Consolelog);
alert(Consolelog.toSource());
```

**But, this give me something like this:**

```
[{
    name: "Some Data 1 ",
    data: {
        length: 4,
        prevObject: {
            0: ({}),
            context: ({}),
            length: 1
        },
        context: ({}),
        selector: "td:not(:nth-child(1))",
        0: ({}),
        1: ({}),
        2: ({}),
        3: ({})
    }},
{
    name: "Some Data 1 ",
    data: {
        length: 4,
        prevObject: {
            0: ({}),
            context: ({}),
            length: 1
        },
        context: ({}),
        selector: "td:not(:nth-child(1))",
        0: ({}),
        1: ({}),
        2: ({}),
        3: ({})
    }}]​
```

**Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: You are doing it inversely. You set a name to first cell in a row, not first cell in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry but i've not much time to test, but this could be a way to do that:

```
var Consolelog = $('table th:not(:nth-child(1))').map(function(i) {

    var $th = $(this);
    var $cel = $('td:nth-child('+(i+2)+')').each(function(){
                       $(this);
                });


    return {
        name: $th.text(),
        data: $cel.text().split('%').slice(0,-1)
    };
    //console.log(return);

}).get();

//console.log(Consolelog);
alert(Consolelog.toSource());
```

See update [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/y2gdq/8/)

UPDATE:

Hi, sorry for the delay, by the way to convert or to be sure that array value are number you could try this:

```
var Consolelog = $('table th:not(:nth-child(1))').map(function(i) {

    var $th = $(this);
    /*var $cel = $('td:nth-child('+(i+2)+')').each(function(){
                       $(this);
                });*/
    var $cel = $.map(
        $('td:nth-child('+(i+2)+')').each(function(){
                       $(this);
        }).text().split('%').slice(0,-1), function(value){
            return parseFloat(value);
        });

    return {
        name: $th.text(),
        //data: $cel.text().split('%').slice(0,-1)
        data: $cel
    };
    //console.log(return);

}).get();

//console.log(Consolelog);
alert(Consolelog.toSource());
```

See example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/y2gdq/9/)

Comment: Great. 99% there. Is there any way to make sure data array is numbers / values and not a strings?

Comment: @NewUser Hi, sorry for the delay but I was away from home, however I have updated the answer, I hope goes well